# Does Google publish IP addresses used for Play Store app testing?

Tags: ip, playback

I have an app in Google's Play Store that had an update rejected recently and the app subsequently pulled. We've corrected the issues, at least I think we have, but Google can't test the app because they keep receiving access errors. I believe these are due to the fact that the application testing is being done from an IP/subnet that we have blocked, perhaps mistakenly, for previous suspected fraudulent activity. I've tried filing appeals and asking for the IP info but have had no success.

Does Google maintain a list of IP addresses they use for testing so I can whitelist them on my servers? If not, is there a better way to contact Google and ask for this information?

Thanks for whatever help you can provide! Apologies if this is the wrong forum to ask this, I am not actually the developer but having to troubleshoot this on behalf of the developer so I'm not as knowledgeable on the community or resources.

Answer (score 0):

@mpardue, I verified that Google provides a json with the IP range of its cloud. Maybe it's the same range used in the Play Store tests:

https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json